# iAd banner in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, iad

I want to add an iAd banner into my UITableViewController. If I drag the iAd into the TableViewController the banner is on top of the cells. But the banner should be at the bottom of the screen (the banner should also be shown if the user scrolls the TableView).

If I run the app the test banner comes up but not on the bottom of the screen.
Does someone knows a solution of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import iAd in your view controller and set the `canDisplayBannerAds` property to `true` on your view controller. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).